# MathJAX not displaying on Webpage

Tags: mathjax

I am trying to enable MathJax on my webpage but it is not working.

I first tried on a simple empty HTML page as follows:

```
    <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
      MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
    </script>

    <div style="offsetWidth: 720; offsetHeight: 54; width: 714px; height: 48px; position: static; top: auto; right: auto; bottom: auto; left: auto; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 6px; margin-left: 0px; color: #000000; display: block; visibility: visible">
    <p>
    </p><p>When $a \ne 0$, there are two solutions to \(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\) and they are<br>$$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.$$</p>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

The above is displaying properly.

But when I incorporate the same on a webpage, where there are other elements and some CSS then I get a "Error preparing HTML-CSS output (preProcess)" and the formulas are replaced by  [MathProcessingError].

I don't know what more information to provide with this question. If you need some more information, please let me know.

Comment: Can you post the full page that is causing problems?  Or provide a URL to it?  It is not easy to diagnose the problem without more details of what is actually on the page in question.  See [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3942/certain-comment-contents-break-latex-rendering-for-the-whole-page) and [this one](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4118/mathjax-bug-upon-page-refresh) for possibly related issues, including how certain mathematics can trigger this.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I have figured out what is wrong. Thanks for the help. If you can answer the question with the links, I can mark it as correct.

Comment: Can you post your solution?

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue today where I was getting the "Error preparing HTML-CSS output (preProcess)" in my message log. I found that I had a global javascript function called "Error" that was catching a message from MathJax of " restart".

Removing the global Error function allowed MathJax to render my  tags without error.